# How to merge hot fix from Tag to Trunk in SVN when not ancestrally related?

Tags: svn

I am new to SVN and my current organization has the following process

```
1)  Trunk (mainline code)
2)  Release-X.0 created from Trunk (for QA and other testing)
3)  Tag-X.0 created from Release-X.0 (to release to customers)
```

So far NO hot-fix has been done on Tag.

In case, hot-fix should be performed on 'Tag-X.0' how can I merge the changes back to 'Trunk'?

If I am not wrong 'Tag-X.0' and 'Trunk' are not ancestrally related or 'Tag-X.0' was NOT created from 'Trunk'

Kindly let me know the solution

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you would commit a hot-fix to Tax-X.0 and that would need to be merged to trunk. In that case I would cherry-pick the hot-fix to trunk.
In trunk checkout:

```
svn merge -c [HOTFIX-REVISION] [Tag-X.0 URL]
svn commit -m "Merged hotfix from Tag-X.0"
```

That should do it.

EDIT: As for ancestry, Tag-X.0 and trunk should be related because Release-X.0 was created (copied I assume) from trunk and then Tag-X.0 from Release-X.0 so the relationship from Trunk to Tag-X.0 should be present.
If this would not be the case and the release and tag would have been created by some other way, and `svn merge -c` would not do anything then you'd need to ignore ancestry for the merge, i.e. call

```
svn merge -c [HOTFIX-REVISION] --ignore-ancestry [Tag-X.0 URL]
```

---

**Longer example**

So the hot-fix that went to Tag-X.0 would have been e.g.

```
timom@dev-machine:~/svn/tagx0$ svn commit --message "Hot-fix for Tag-X.0"
Sending        services/foo/bar.cpp
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 30816.
timom@dev-machine:~/svn/tagx0$
```

And the merge to trunk

```
timom@dev-machine:~/svn/trunk$ svn merge -c 30816 ^/tags/X.0
--- Merging differences between repository URLs into '.':
U    services/foo/bar.cpp
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge between repository URLs into '.':
 U   .
 U   services
timom@dev-machine:~/svn/trunk$  svn commit -m "Merged hotfix from Tag-X.0"
Sending        services/foo/bar.cpp
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 30817.
timom@dev-machine:~/svn/trunk$
```

Comment: Going to implement hot fix in shortly.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I edited my answer to contain some info about ancestry.